# Offset data from one column to another based on specific condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to offset some data to another column. The data exist in column A and B. The code I am using is:

```
Sub data_shifter()
Dim A As Range, r As Range
Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))

For Each r In A

    If Mid(r, 4, 1) = "-" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 15)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

This code is looking for all the strings in column A where `-` is the fourth character. What I want is the first three characters should be numeric and the fourth character is `-`. Also, if the above situation is true the data in column B should be offset too.

For example, if column A2 has `333-m1233232` it should offset to p2 and data in column B2 should offset to Q2

Comment: Try putting this `Range(r,r.offset(,1)).copy r.offset(,15)` in place of `r.Copy r.Offset(0, 15)`

Comment: thanks yes it works but I want only for data that is numeric on first 3 characters and - on forth character something like 888-fdersfdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub data_shifter()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
      If IsNumeric(Left(r, 3)) And Mid(r, 4, 1) = "-" Then
        r.Resize(1, 2).Copy r.Offset(0, 15)
        r.Clear
      End If
    Next r
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents,

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range    
    Set rng = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Mid(c, 1, 3)) Then

            MsgBox " Do your thing"    'what ever you want after that
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```